# Finding a clash for the inserted data based on time and date

Tags: c++, datetime, data-structures

I have a DateTime class that takes the day, month, year, hour and minute as input.

I am trying to implement a timetable structure and am trying to implement a way to find a clash for the inserted data.

This creates an instance of the class:

```
DateTime DT(18, 03, 2018, 12, 15);
```

I would then like to check if the instance exists in the timetable structure.

```
list <DateTime> Date;
Date.push_front(DT);
```

This attempts to check if the data exists in the timetable:

```
 list<int>::iterator iter = std::find(Date.begin(), Date.end(), DT);

    if (Date.end() == iter)
    {
        std::cout << "item not found" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Collision at DateTime:" << DT << std::endl;
    }
```

However, I have an error with the std::find because:

Error (active)  E0312   no suitable user-defined conversion from "std::_List_iterator, std::_List_iter_types *>>>>" to "std::_List_iterator, std::_List_iter_types *>>>>" exists

How do I resolve this error to find a clash for the inserted data?

Answer (score 1):

Use `list<DateTime>::iterator` instead of `list<int>`

Comment: @JimMischel it looks like a correct answer to me. `std::find(Date.begin(), Date.end(), DT);` will return a `list<DateTime>::iterator` which is not convertible to `list<int>::iterator`. Some further explanation in this answer would be nice.

Comment: @alterigel The edited question does answer the question. The original answer was ... ambiguous.